# How to define parallel stages of a Jenkinsfile in an external function?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

This minimal pipeline works:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            parallel {
                stage('test-1') {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo test1"
                    }
                }
                stage('test-2') {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo test2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have several test stages inside the `parallel` block and so we run into [Method Code too large](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37984) error that the Jenkins guys apparently aren't planning to fix.

I'd like to have my parallel stages defined in an outside function, like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            parallel test_func()
        }
    }
}

def test_func() {
    return {
            stage('test-1') {
                steps {
                    sh "echo test1"
                }
            }
            stage('test-2') {
                steps {
                    sh "echo test2"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This however doesn't work with lots of variations of syntax that we've tried.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `parallel` needs a list (`[ .. ]`) and I would say it should include two entries (wrapped in `{ .. }` each) that contain one `stage` each.

Comment: Correction, not a list, but a map, see below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926419/jenkins-parallel-build-on-different-agents).

You need to put your parallel stages in a variable, not a function. So, it could be somethink like this:

```
def test_func = [
    "test1": {
        echo "test1"
    },
    "test2": {
        echo "test2"
    }
]

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel test_func
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the examples [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/), it expects a map of an arbitrary identifier as key and a closure containing the code as value. So something (untested) like:

```java
def test_func() {
    return [
        test1: {
            stage('test-1') {
                steps {
                    sh "echo test1"
                }
            }
        },
        test2: {
            stage('test-2') {
                steps {
                    sh "echo test2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting 
```
WorkflowScript: 4: Expected a block for parallel @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('test') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 4: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "test" @ line 4, column 9.
           stage('test') {
```
where line 4 is:
```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            parallel test_func()
```

Comment: Ah, you're in the scripted context, so `steps` stanzas have to be removed.

Comment: But that's just a subsequent thing.. can't try it from here, but something like either return the returned list in `( .. )` or add these parentheses after `parallel`? I'm really not sure here, maybe search for few more examples.

Comment: As stated, "doesn't work with lots of variations of syntax that we've tried." I'm in Declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
def createStages() {
  stage_map = [:]
  stage_map.put('test-1', {echo 'test1'})
  stage_map.put('test-2', {echo 'test2'})
  return stage_map
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('test') {
      steps{
        script { parallel(createStages()) }
      }
    }
  }
}
```